# Tool that lists possible departure locations for a selected flight destination

Tags: web-apps, travel, software

These days I fly a lot by business necessity. I frequently use websites like **Skyscanner** and **Google Flights** to find cheap flights from/to different locations.

I particularly enjoy the feature of selecting a **departure location**, and listing flights from all over a region. Here is a photo of using this particular feature:

[image: Listing flights from Chicago to all over US using Skyscanner]

I chose Chicago as the departure location, and listed flights to all destinations from there. They are also sorted by their respective ticket prices.

I am looking for a website/tool that possesses the *reverse* of this feature. In this case, **selecting a destination** and listing possible departure locations, sorted by ticket prices.